# I am gettting TLE on Hackerrank how can I optimize the Scala code? I am trying to solve the maximum element problem on hackerrank

Tags: java, scala, jvm

```
def getMax(operations: Array[String]): ArrayBuffer[Int] = {
    // Write your code here
        var a: ArrayBuffer[Int] = mutable.ArrayBuffer()
        val s = mutable.Stack[Int]()
        val check_1 = (s:String) => s.contains(" ") && (s.substring(0,1).toInt.equals(1))
        val check_2 = (s:String) => (s.contains(" ") || !s.contains(" ")) && (s.substring(0,1).toInt.equals(2))
        val check_3 = (s:String) => (s.contains(" ") || !s.contains(" ")) && (s.substring(0,1).toInt.equals(3))
        val check_4 = (s:String) => s.substring(0,1).toInt.equals(1)
        for(i <- operations) yield {
            i match {
                case w if(check_1(i)) => s.push(i.substring(2,(i.length)).toInt)
                case d if(check_2(i)) => s.pop
                case q if(check_3(i))=> a :+= s.max
                case t if(check_4(i)) => s.push(i.substring(1,(i.length)).toInt)
                case _ =>
                }
            }
            a
    }
```

and

```
  def getMax(ops:Array[String]): Array[Int] ={
    var a: Array[Int] = Array()  // This is the cache for storing the max
    val s = mutable.Stack[Int]()
    for(i <- ops) {
      if(i.contains(" ") && (i.substring(0,1).toInt.equals(1)))  s.push(i.substring(2,(i.length)).toInt)
      else if((i.contains(" ") || !i.contains(" ")) && (i.substring(0,1).toInt.equals(2))) s.pop
      else if((i: .contains(" ") || !i.contains(" "))&& (i.substring(0,1).toInt.equals(3))) a :+= s.max
      else if(i.substring(0,1).toInt.equals(1)) s.push(i.substring(1,(i.length)).toInt)
    }
    a
  }
```

I tried both solutions and they all have a TLE(Time Limit Exceeded). any help on how to optimize it?
Link to question: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/maximum-element/problem

Comment: It will help if you put description of the problem in your question. External links have tendency to rot.

Comment: ok, will take note of that

Answer (score 1):

You need to maintain ordered list of object you have in stack along with stack itself.

This way you will have `O(1)` complexity for getting max value in stack.